# Get Name of CheckList Items from Content Item in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have an item in Sitecore that contains a content section which is a Checklist.  This checklist contains the names of multiple Active Directory groups that I have entered into Sitecore.

When the item loads, I am trying to loop through all of the names that are in the Checklist so that I can see if the user is a member of one of these groups, if checked.

When testing my code, I cannot obtain the ID's "display" value (not sure if this is the correct termonology), such as "IT_Support_Group". Instead, I can only get the Item Id.

```
Example: {80B1AEEA-D36C-416C-B5BF-AF5F428E4D31}
```

I've been playing around with various versions of the following code, but with no luck:

```
    Dim ADCheckList As Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields("ADGroupAccess")

    If ADCheckList IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each ADListName As String In ADCheckList.Items
           'If IsInGroup(ADListName) and IsADListItemChecked(ADListName) Then
           '   Response.Write("User is in the " & ADListName & " selected group.<br/>"
           'End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: If you turn Raw Values on, how are the values stored?  Is it a pipe-delmited list of ID's or something else?

Comment: Yes, pipe-delimited list of ID's

Comment: Then, yes, as you've probably confirmed, all you were missing was the call to GetItems().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close .. you need to call the `GetItems()` method (instead of the `Items` property) which will resolve the item ID's into an array of Sitecore `Item` objects.

You can then call properties such as `item.Name` or retrieve a specific field using .. `item.Fields[FieldName].Value`.